# Ugly GUI for appliction under root

Tags: themes, gui, root

When I start a program with root privilege the GUI looks like win98 and applications like: gparted, bum, gufw, mousepad looks ugly.

My themes are in /usr/share/theme so it doesn't matter if I make a link to .**theme** directory for root user, however I already done this and it doesn't worked.

I also created a link to gtk-3 configuration in /root directory, even coping all config files (gtk2, gtk3, etc) to /root directory doesn't makes any different.

My theme is Adwaita, as you know it's supports both gtk-2 and gtk-3.

The command I use to run applications that I mentioned before is (e.g. gkso bum, gksu gparted from openbox menu or gmrun).

I tried sudo gparted, sudo bum, sudo mousepad, from terminal and it's seems everyting is okay when I use sudo.

but gksu doesn't work properly and for gufw sudo does not work too.

i also tried gparted-pkexec, sudo gparted-pkexec, gksu gparted-pkexec and no difference, but as I saied before sudo gparted works fine.

how can I get make gksu work properly?

Comment: What application? Are you sure it's using GTK+ 3.x?

Comment: for example: gparted, gufw, mousepad, bum

Comment: As regards gparted, any difference if you don't use sudo but start it with `gparted-pkexec`?

Comment: Can you please edit your question, and show us an **exact** command example when you "start a program with root privilege"?

Comment: Only one of those that is gtk+ 3.x based, is gufw. The other 3 are gtk+ 2.x, so if you are using a theme that is gtk+ 3.x only, it won't apply to gtk+ 2.x apps.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: According to me, it's also so that you don't open the application very often. (You'll get the ugly face)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I fixed the problem using:

```
gksu lxappearance
```

then I set `Adwaita` as default theme for root user, everything works fine know.

Comment: Valid accordingly for other desktops (e'.g. Plasma) with other ways of running as root (`sudo` or `pkexec`.)